# Are two spaces obtained from homeomorphic spaces by removing a ball still homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I have a specific example in mind. Consider $S_1,S_2$ two surfaces. Remove two discs to obtain surfaces with boundary $S_1',S_2'.$ If $S_1 \cong S_2,$ does it necessarily follow that $S_1' \cong S_2'$? It seems intuitively true (having the classification of surfaces in mind), but the homeomorphism does not descend to an obvious homeomorphism to the $S_i'$ (since one of the removed discs is not necessarily sent to the other).

More generally, does this hold for $n$-manifolds with $n$-balls? What if we remove more complicated (e.g. non simply connected) submanifolds?

Thanks!

Comment: Removing more complicated submanifolds is not the same as removing balls: consider the case of knots in $S^3$.

Answer (score 1):

It holds for all manifolds in all dimensions. This is a consequence of the [Annulus Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_theorem). The immediate corollary of the annulus theorem that you need is the following. Consider two balls $B,B'$ in a connected manifold $M$. You'll need to assume these are "coordinate balls" meaning that they are closed unit balls in some coordinate chart; I will guess that you surely intended this to be the case. Then there exists a homeomorphism of $M$ taking $B$ to $B'$.

For surfaces, it does indeed follow from the classification of surfaces, because removal of a ball does not affect genus, it does not affect orientability, and it increases the number of boundary components by $1$, and those quantities classify the surface up to homeomorphism.

Comment: As a counterexample for *open* balls, delete a sufficiently large open ball from $\Bbb{RP}^2$ (if you view $\Bbb{RP}^2$ as a quotient of the sphere, delete the upper hemisphere; if you view it as the projective plane, delete the plane itself, leaving only the points at infinity).

Comment: Interesting... so it is a nontrivial fact. I was wondering because I'm looking at Donaldson's Morse-theoretical proof of the classification of surfaces (so obviously I can't use that to prove it...), and he states essentially this: Take a closed surface $S$, cut a disk $D$, and attach a twisted band to the boundary $S-D$ to get a surface $S'$ with boundary $\partial S' = S^1$. Now if we attach a disk to the boundary, we get $S \# \mathbb{R}P^2$, so that $S' \cong (S \# \mathbb{R}P^2) - \text{disk}.$ Is it just me overcomplicating things, or do we need this result to arrive to the conclusion?

Comment: I'll point out that in the differentiable category, in which Donaldson is certainly working, you do not need the full power of the Annulus Theorem. The corollary I mention has a direct proof in the differentiable category.

Comment: I see. Do you have a particular reference in mind for the result in the differentiable category?